# .NET - Error in Google Drive REST API v3 - exporting old spreadsheets

Tags: google-drive-api

I am attempting to use the Drive REST API (v3) to download/export documents from Google Drive.  Among these documents are some spreadsheets which are failing to export.

I am using the DriveService.Files.Export(fileId, mimetype) method to try and export these google spreadsheets as Excel files (mimetype = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet").

Error information:

> Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
>   Internal Error [500]
>   Errors [
>           Message[Internal Error] Location[ - ] Reason[internalError] Domain[global]
>   ]
>
> at Google.Apis.Download.MediaDownloader.d__17.MoveNext() in C:\Users\mdril\Documents\GitHub\google-api-dotnet-client\Src\GoogleApis\Apis[Media]\Download\MediaDownloader.cs:line 214

Upon closer investigation of the files throwing the error, all of them appear to be older format spreadsheets (accessed via a Google docs URL containing '/spreadsheet/ccc?key=[fileId]')

The message seems to indicate the issue resides within the API.  Can anyone confirm this and advise whether it should be raised as an issue?

Cheers,
nibrox

Comment: In my experience, when trying to export old Spreadsheets to the new Spreadsheets,  most of the times i can get it just by making a copy of the file, after that the new file is in the new Spreadsheets.  When this doesn't work, it has to be done manually. check this: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/UC-SWkSmHYo